# How do mobile apps typically manage user sessions?

Tags: session, mobile

I am a web developer making a mobile app. I have a Ruby on Rails backend for the mobile client. When a user signs up, it needs to create a new user or sign in; then it needs to fetch data for the user.

I don't want to require them to enter a username and password. It just should be seamlessly associated with their device/phone number/FB account/whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right,
you can either use Facebook API or normal logging form. Then just make sure to enable automatic logging in and user won't have to enter data.